# Compile Time & Memory Usage of a large C++ Project?

Tags: c++, linux

Suppose one has about 50,000 different `.cpp` files.

Each `.cpp` file contains **just one class** that has about ~1000 lines of code in it (the code itself is not complicated -- involves in-memory operations on matrices & vectors -- i.e, no special libraries are used).

I need to build a project (in a `Linux` environment) that will have to import & use all of these 50,000 different `.cpp` files.

A couple of questions come to mind:

1. How long will it roughly take to compile this? What will be the approx. size of the compiled file?
2. What would be a better approach -- keep 50,000 different `.so` files (compiled extenstions) and have the main program import them one by one, or alternatively, unite these 50,000 different `.cpp` files into *one large* `.cpp` *file*, and just deal with that?  Which method will be faster / more efficient?

Any insights are greatly appreicated.

Comment: No one is going to be able to answer part 1 of your question. The time to compile the program and its resulting size is _highly_ dependent on what the code actually is.

Comment: ".so files (compiled extenstions) ... unite these 50,000 different .cpp files into one large .cpp " A .so is the non-Windows equivalent of a .DLL. You don't compile .cpp files into .so files; you compile them into object files (.o, .obj, or whatever), which are all linked into either some form of library, either static (.a) or dynamic (.so). It doesn't matter to the .so building process that there were many .cpp files or just one. So the use of a .so has nothing to do with how many .cpp files you had.

Comment: Our usual response of "please post your code" would probably bad advice with regards to 50K source files. :)

Comment: @selbie: He could merge them into one I am sure.

Comment: Just to illustrate James' point, it's possible to write a C++ program which will solve the N queens problem at compile time, if you try to compile this smallish program to solve a board 30x30 it'll probably take the rest of time on earth to build your program and the size of the binary would be larger than your hard drive.

Comment: @Benj : [Obligatory link](http://debugfailure.wordpress.com/2009/12/16/but-but-its-still-compiling/).

Comment: Just do `cat *.cpp > all.cpp; time g++ all.cpp` and you got an answer to question 1 ;-)

Comment: And of course -1 for question part 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(i) There are way too many factors involved in determining this, even an approximation is impossible. Compilation can be memory, cpu or hard drive bound. The complexity of the files matter (from your description, your complexity is low).

(ii) The typical way of doing this is to make a library and let the system figure out linking or loading. You can choose static or dynamic linking.

**static linking**
Assuming you are using gcc, this would look like this:

`g++ -c file1.cpp -o file1.o

g++ -c file2.cpp -o file2.o

...

g++ -c filen.cpp -o filen.o

ar -rc libvector.a file1.o file2.o ... filen.o`

Then, when you build your own code, your final link looks like this:
`g++ myfile.cpp libvector.a -o mytask`

**dynamic linking**
Again, assuming you are using gcc, this would look like this:
`g++ -c file1.cpp -fPIC -o file1.o

g++ -c file2.cpp -fPIC -o file2.o

...

g++ -c filen.cpp -fPIC -o filen.o

ld -G file1.o file2.o ... filen.o -o libvector.so`

Then, when you build your own code, your final link looks like this:
`g++ myfile.cpp libvector.so -o mytask`
You will need libvector.so to be in the loader's path for your executable to work.

In any case, as long as the 50,000 files don't change, you will only need to do the last command (which will be much faster).

Comment: Thank you Jerome; So as long as the 50,000 files remain the same, I will only need to run the final line whenever my 'main' `.cpp` file changes, correct?  Also, what if I have one more file (50,001) -- must I really compile all the `.o` files together? or is there a way around it?

Comment: That depends on how you want to organize your code. If you feel like that 50001th file belongs with the other 50000 lines, you will need to compile that single file (g++ -c filen.cpp -o filen.o) and rebuild the archive/shared object (the ar or the ld command) with the extra file. If you don't think they go together, compile the file (g++ -c filen.cpp -o filen.o) and then add that to the final link (g++ myfile.cpp filen.o libvector.a/libvector.so -o mytask)

Answer (score 2):

There is no answer, just advice.

Right back at you: **What are you really trying to do?** Are you trying to make a code library from different source files?  Or is that an executable?  Did you actually code that many .cpp files?

50,000 source files is well... a massively sized project.  Are you trying to do something common across all files (e.g. every source file represents a resource, record, image, or something unique). Or it just 50K disparate code files?

Most of your compile time will not be based on the size of each source file. It will be based on the amount of header files (and the headers they include) that will be brought in with each cpp file.  Headers, while not usually containing implementations, just declarations, have to go through a compile process.  And redundant headers across the code base can slow your build time down.

Large projects at that kind of scale use [precompiled headers](http://www.bing.com/search?q=precompiled+header&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=precompiled+header&sc=8-18&sp=-1&sk=).  You can include all the commonly used header files in one header file (common.h) and build common.h.  Then all the other source files just include "common.h".  The compiler can be configured to automatically use the compiled header file when it sees the #include "common.h" for each source.

Comment: That massive header you're proposing brings other issues with it, e.g. the need to rebuild the whole project just because one header changed. It also massively works against e.g. ccache which is a decent solution if he's really having build time problems.

Comment: @honk. Right. Typically, you only put system header files, CRT includes (stdio.h and friends), and project header files that rarely change static (yet commonly used).   But with our projects at work, we've found that with some dedicated tuning of the precomp files, you can greatly improve the efficiency of individual developers. YMMV. But I think the discussion of precomp headers is a tangent from the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can build each object file from a '.cpp' with having the '.h' file having lots (and I MEAN LOTS) of forward declarations - so when you change a `.h` file it does not need to recompile the rest of the program. Usually a function/method needs the name of the object in its parmaters or what it is returing. If it needs other details - yes it needs to be included.

Please get a book by Scott Myers - Will help you a lot.

Oh - When trying to eat a big cake - divied it up. The slices are more manageable.

Answer (score 0):

We can't really say the time it will take to compile, but what you should do is compile each `.cpp`/`.h` pair into a `.o` file:

```
$ g++ -c -o test.o test.cpp ...
```

Once you have all of these, you compile the main program as so:

```
$ g++ -c -o main.o main.cpp
$ g++ -o main main.o test.o blah.o otherThings.o foo.o bar.o baz.o etc...
```

Your idea of using `.so`s is pretty much asking "how quickly can I crash the program and possibly the OS?". Shared libraries are ment for large libraries in small numbers, not 50,000 `.so`s linked to a binary (*especially* if you load them dynamicly...that would be ***BAD***).